# USB OTG not showing WiFi network even after drivers are installed in Android kernel

Tags: adb, usb-on-the-go, kernel

I am trying to connect to WiFi using a USB WiFi stick by making use of OTG on my Android Nexus 6. The USB WiFi stick has a separate AP. However, I am unable to see this AP in the list of available WiFi networks on my android phone.

I have installed a CROM with a custom kernel including the drivers of the WiFi stick. I can see the drivers and firmware being loaded using dmesg:

```
[ 3480.147186] usb 3-1: new high-speed USB device number 2 using xhci-hcd
[ 3480.161788] usb 3-1: New USB device found, idVendor=2ef5, idProduct=0008
[ 3480.161807] usb 3-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[ 3480.161819] usb 3-1: Product: Dongle
[ 3480.161829] usb 3-1: Manufacturer: WiFi
[ 3480.161838] usb 3-1: SerialNumber: AB1018S052
[ 3480.174615] wifi 3-1:1.0: Firmware Version: 10441, $Revision: 13790 $
[ 3480.176511] ieee80211 phy9: Selected rate control algorithm 'minstrel_ht'
[ 3480.180991] ueventd: firmware: loading 'wifi/wifi_x/fpga_xc.bit' for '/devices/f9200000.ssusb/f9200000.dwc3/xhci-hcd.0.auto/usb3/3-1/3-1:1.0/firmware/wifi!wifi_x!fpga_xc.bit'
[ 3480.195460] ueventd: loading /devices/f9200000.ssusb/f9200000.dwc3/xhci-hcd.0.auto/usb3/3-1/3-1:1.0/firmware/wifi!wifi_x!fpga_xc.bit took 14ms
[ 3481.666134] wifi 3-1:1.0: probe::FPGA download success.
```

Also, there is a light on the stick that turns green when the drivers are recognized. So, I can say with surety that the drivers are loaded and the device is recognized. However, the WiFi AP for USB stick is not appearing.

When I do the same thing on my Ubuntu laptop, after loading drivers I can connect to two different WiFi networks at the same time, one with built-in WiFi card and the other with USB stick. But I believe this cannot be done with Android, where you can connect to one WiFi at a time.

I suspect that even after the drivers are loaded, Android is only scanning WiFi networks available to built-in WiFi card. Is there a possibility to disable the built-in WiFi in Android and make the Android OS scan WiFi networks available to USB WiFi stick as well?

Thank you.

Comment: Do you get a network interface on Android when USB WiFi stick is connected?

Comment: @IrfanLatif No, I can't see any additional active interfaces using ifconfig in adb shell.

Comment: Neither in `/sys/class/net/`?

Comment: @IrfanLatif: There are following interfaces, but these interfaces exist even without installing the device drivers:

127|shamu:/ # ls /sys/class/net/                                               
dummy0/         r_rmnet_data3/  r_rmnet_data8/  rmnet_data4/    sit0/
lo/             r_rmnet_data4/  rmnet_data0/    rmnet_data5/    usb0/
r_rmnet_data0/  r_rmnet_data5/  rmnet_data1/    rmnet_data6/    wlan0/
r_rmnet_data1/  r_rmnet_data6/  rmnet_data2/    rmnet_data7/
r_rmnet_data2/  r_rmnet_data7/  rmnet_data3/    rmnet_usb0/

Comment: Seems like the problem is with your driver. Also confirm with `iw dev | grep Interface` and `cat /proc/net/wireless`.

Comment: @IrfanLatif: There is an interface with wlan1 with the name of the device in the Driver name as well. Can you tell how can I scan over wlan1 interface rather than default wlan0 interface and connect to a WiFi over it?

**2|shamu:/ # iw dev | grep Interface                                            
 Interface wlan1
 Interface wlan0
shamu:/ # ifconfig wlan1
wlan1     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 70:b3:d5:95:85:fe  Driver lifi
          BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1**

Comment: `iw dev wlan1 scan`. But for that interface should be UP.

Comment: Try `iw wlan1 interface add wlan1 type managed && ip link set dev wlan1 up`.

Comment: Or `iw phy phy9 interface add wlan1 type managed && ip link set dev wlan1 up`.