# Is it possible to use 5Ghz OTG WiFi adapters on Android?

Tags: wi-fi, rooting, usb-on-the-go

My phone is Xiaomi Redmi 6A. I cannot detect 5Ghz WiFi on my phone. Is there a way to use an external 5Ghz WiFi adapter(connected via OTG) to add 5Ghz WiFi capability? My phone is rooted, and I am ok to make modifications/ install drivers to support the adapter.

Comment: There are several videos on youtube showing how to do this with other products. Basically you need to be root to manually create the network interfaces, a prerequisite you have already, and then you would need the ARM source code for the device to make a kernel module (essentially the driver) which would be a but tougher. Even with that, other questions here, all unanswered, seem to show this is a much more complex task then it appears. Here is one example: https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/214579

Comment: Thanks. I cannot seem to find any videos on YouTube though, could you show me one?

Comment: https://lmgtfy.com/?q=USB+OTG+wifi+android&s=g